# What is wrong with my jQuery src changing code?

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, src, attr

I am trying to change an images's src when you hover over it.  This was my attempt, however it is not working:

HTML:

```
<img src="images/work.png" id="work"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#work").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/workH.png");
    });
    $("#work").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/work.png");
    });
});
```

Edit 1:
@Erik: 
I tried this code again, but instead with a 200x200px img.  The code worked fine.  Is it perhaps that my logo images are just too small?

Edit2:
I figured out the problem!  Sorry for the hassle guys.  But thanks for your help with this.

I had a logo image written above the work image. It was in a float state allowing the work image to rest below it.  Most of the logo image is transparent, making the work image viewable.
However, when i moused over my images, they didn't change because the logo was in the way.

*Facepalm moment*

Comment: *It's not working*, that means?

Comment: If you can, look at doing this with a div and a background with a `:hover` pseudo selector.  CSS already provides the functionality to change the image on hover so unless you're doing something further, there's no point in writing extra js when the functionality is already built for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Nothing**. It should work fine as it is. Are your two images different? Is the jQuery library included?

---

You can simplify your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#work").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/workH.png");
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/work.png");
    });
});
```

Comment: If you're really that into simplification, you might want to substitute `$(this).attr(` with `$.attr(this, `. It's *much* faster.

Comment: @JosephSilber: Simplification != optimization. Also, is that really true?

Comment: Both images are different and correctly linked. I have jQuery v1.7.2 from jquery.com attached to my HTML. Would it help if I showed you the rest of the HTML?

Comment: @Eric - You're right. My bad. As for whether it is true; it definitely is. Paul Irish has been talking about this a lot lately. When you do `$(this)`, you're creating a brand new jQuery object *with all its methods and properties*! By just using `$[methodName](this, params)`, you're using the main jQuery object.

Comment: @JosephSilber: Interesting. Do you have any links to blogs discussing that?

Comment: @Eric - See this slide from Paul: http://www.slideshare.net/paul.irish/perfcompression/51